# Neural Network implementation for unsupervised clustering

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am relatively new to the neural network, so I was trying to use it for unsupervised clustering. My data is in `dataframe` with 5 different columns (features), I wanted to get like 4 classes from this, see the full model below

---

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing as pp
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve, average_precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, roc_auc_score

import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout , Flatten
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Input, Lambda
from keras import regularizers
from keras.losses import mse, categorical_crossentropy

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu',input_shape=[5]))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = "softmax"))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])
```

---

when I give the option of generating 4 classes I get the error message:

> ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 4) are incompatible

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have tried to use a different loss function, same error.

i get the error when i input my data,

```
out_class = model.fit(x=pd_pca_std,
                      y=pd_pca_std,
                      epochs=num_epochs,
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      shuffle=True,
                      validation_data=(pd_pca_std, pd_pca_std),
                      verbose=1)
```

the values are

```
batch_size = 33
epochs = 20
num_classes = 4
input_shape = (990000, 5)
output_shape = (990000, 4)
```

Comment: Post code that allows people to replicate your problem.

Comment: i have added all the imports library.

Comment: I get no errors running this using both```keras``` and ```tf.keras```

Comment: when i made the last layer 5, same as the number of columns as the input, it run without error. But, i am interested in having only 4 classes.

Comment: Are you getting the error with this exact code that you have posted because like I said. I get no errors with this and I am able to get a model. Or are you getting an error when you try to input your data

Comment: yes, this same code, i get the error when i input my data,                              
 ,'out_class = model.fit(x=pd_pca_std, y=pd_pca_std,epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
                    shuffle=True,validation_data=(pd_pca_std,pd_pca_std),verbose=1)'

Comment: Well like I said, this runs without errors on my machine so there must be something that you are omitting or one of your modules may need to be updated. My only other guess is that you are omitting something from the question

Comment: You should've included that in your question.

Comment: Now that you have specified that the problem is when you try to fit the model it makes sense. Please edit your question again to include the shape of your input data and output data. That way we can determine the correct input shape of your data. Also include all the necessary variables such as num_epochs etc for replications sake

Comment: batch_size = 33
epochs = 20
num_classes = 4           input shape = (990000, 5), output shape(990000, 4)

Comment: Ok yet again I have done everything you say you are doing and I'm still not getting any errors and then model trains and predicts just fine. Maybe include a sample of your input and output data. Also, when people ask for more information such as values of certain variables etc. please add all the relevant information to the question. That's the best way to do it.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that you are using the exact same variable as your input and output data.

Comment: This network does not do clustering, did you mean to use an autoencoder?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using 5 classes or something relative to the 5 classes instead. I'll explain.

So in Neural Networks and machine learning in general, there are certain matrix operations that happen in the background in TensorFlow. So say I create the following:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random((3, 4))
y = np.random.random((3, 3))

np.dot(x, y)  # if I try multiplying 2 incompatible matrices, the program will fail :(
```

So what's happening here is that the matrices are incompatible for simple matrix arithmetic, because they need to be certain shapes for them to be compatible. So what I recommend doing is either changing the shapes of the matrices/arrays in question, or play with different shapes in the program to see which will succeed...

You could also learn some linear algebra which has the rules for matrix manipulation and arithmetic, but I won't go into that right now. However, what I will do is leave a link for you to check out regarding this subject so you know what to do in the future...

Here it is:
https://www.mathlynx.com/online/LinAlg_Matrices_rules

Hopefully this helps...
Have a nice day :)

**TL;DR**

Your output units should match the number of classes you are testing on.

Comment: thanks, infact if i use number of classes same as the shape of the input columns, it works, so i just wanted to know if for neural network in unsupervised clustering number of cluster must be same as input shape.

Comment: Ah ok. Just for knowledge sake, did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is the skeleton of how I replicated you problem and had it working

```
from sklearn import preprocessing as pp
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve, average_precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, roc_auc_score

import numpy as np

import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout , Flatten
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Input, Lambda
from keras import regularizers
from keras.losses import mse, categorical_crossentropy

X = '''input data here as an array''' # I used X = np.zeros((990000, 5))
y = '''output data here as an array'''#I used y = np.ones((990000, 4))

batch_size = 33 
num_epochs = 20 
num_classes = 4

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu',input_shape=X.shape[1:])) #Input shape = 5
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation = "softmax")) #Output = y.shape[1] = 4
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary() #Will show you a summary of the model

model.fit(x=X, y=y,epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,validation_data=(X,y),verbose=1) #You may want to use different variables in your validation.
```

Comment: I would just like to add that this will run and be able to make predictions however I don't think it does what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for these, it actually works, my understanding is that the last dense layers must have the same dimension as the output. But for unsupervised learning where you dont have labels, running it now just to see the results.

Comment: If it does end up working for you please mark the answer

Comment: It work, In the sense that I have to make the y the same dimension as the required output,  x = (8000,5) and y=(8000,4) to get 4 classes. I  am not sure why I really can't explain why it work or if the output I am getting is the correct one.